# Is it possible to forbid to implement interface directly

Tags: php, interface

Is it possible to forbid to implement interface directly? Instead of this class must implement descendant of this interface (like [***Traversable***](http://php.net/Traversable)).

Comment: Never heard of a descendant of an interface. Could you please elaborte what you mean? Could you provide a little pseudo-code for example to illustrate what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Traversable*** is an internal interface. There are no descendants of it. It's just that when you're in PHP userland (that his where you write PHP code) you can not implement ***Traversable*** directly but only one of those two which are a ***Traversable***, too:

1. [***Iterator***](http://php.net/class.iterator)
2. [***IteratorAggregate***](http://php.net/IteratorAggregate)

But the reason is not that there is some descendant relation that you could control in PHP userspace, but only that ***Traversal*** is an internal interface not available for you in userspace.

Apart from interfaces, what you can do is to create an abstract class which can not be instantiated. You later on ask for that abstract type:

```
abstract class Mineable 
{
   // ...
}

class MineAggregate extends Mineable 
{
   // ...
}

class Mine extends Mineable
{
   // ...
}
```

Those aren't interfaces, for a good reason. The ***Traversable*** example might have misguided you, it should normally not be done what's been done there. See as well:

- [Interface or an Abstract Class: which one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1814821/367456)

So naturally you can build this up with interfaces as well, however *any* interface can be implemented:

```
interface Mineable {} // this interface is empty just for the taste of it

interface MineAggregate extends Mineable 
{
   // ...
}

interface Mine extends Mineable
{
   // ...
}
```

I don't know if that is what you're looking for, your question was not really clear to me I must admit.

Comment: thanks for exhaustive answer. I`m looking for such strcucture:

interface PaymentSystem{}
interface Sort1PaymentSystem extends PaymentSystem{
 public function check();
}
interface Sort2PaymentSystem extends PaymentSystem {
 publick function create();
}
class Payer {
 //$ps_handler must implement one of Sort1PaymentSystem or 
 //Sort2PaymentSystem. Not PaymentSystem directly
 public function pay(PaymentSystem $ps_handler) {}
}

Answer (score 0):

it may be possible to define your interface with the `protected` keyword, so only classes in the same package can implement the interface.

Comment: You've seen that the question is tagged PHP?